# How to raise all number in list to the power of their index

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to raise all numbers in a list to the power of their position in the list (index). I want to use list comprehension and know how to do so but don't know how to format it to raise each number to the power of their index 'i'.

```
power_list([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
```

This is how my code should run after it is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) in the [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like:

#### Code:

```
[x ** i for i, x in enumerate(data)]
```

#### Test Code:

```
data = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]

print([x ** i for i, x in enumerate(data)])
```

#### Results:

```
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
```

Comment: def power_list(weak_list):                                                                                                           
   strong_list = [n**i for i, x in (weak_list)]
    print(strong_list)
 power_list([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])                        #can u see why this code will not run

Comment: try: `x**i` not `n**i`

Comment: That did not work either. The type error states that an int is not iterable

Comment: you also forgot the `enumerate`

Answer (score 0):

If `l` is your list, you can do:

```
[num**index for index, num in enumerate(l)]
```

Comment: def power_list(weak_list):     strong_list = [num**index for index, number in (weak_list)]
Is this what you mean. This doesn't work either.

Comment: Yep, was missing the enumerate. Thanks for the help!